# Is there any way of prompt a message when a command in /usr/sbin/ is tried to run as nonroot?

Tags: debian, command-line, non-root-user

In most Linux distros I've used when you type for example *ifconfig* as a normal user, you get a prompt message telling you that only root can execute such command.

In Debian, it only says command not found (because it's looking for it in /usr/bin/).

I'm wondering if there is any way for prompt a message, like "ifconfig must be run as root" or something like that.

Comment: You should be able to execute `ifconfig` as a regular user. I have never seen `ifconfig` issuing such a prompt message in its default capacity.

Comment: 70% of the commands in `*/sbin` don't need superuser privilege. If a command needs superuser priviledge, it will tell you. It's safer not to run a command as root, so I'd rather issue the opposite warning like _beware, this is run as root_ when not needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this :

```
trap '
    if [[ $BASH_COMMAND =~ /sbin ]] && ((UID!=0)); then
        echo >&2 "${BASH_COMMAND##*/sbin/} must be run as root"
    fi
' DEBUG
```

But `ifconfig` is accessible for users too, just need to type `/sbin/ifconfig`.

Like Chris Down said, I have never seen `ifconfig` issuing such a prompt message in its default capacity.

Comment: +1 for telling me about =~ BASH_COMMAND and DEBUG in one post.

But this solution will only work if the sbin folders are in path and the binary is actually about to be exectuted, won't it. This already implies execute rights for non root user which does semantically collide with the intention and error message. But I'm just trying to be smart :-)

Comment: yep, seem it was a problem of PATH. Btw, where should I write that? I tried in .bashrc but nothing changed.

Comment: Did you source your .bashrc or close and open a new terminal?

Answer (score 0):

> In Debian, it only says command not found (because it's looking for it in /usr/bin/)

That just means your non-root users don't have `/sbin` in their PATH. Run `/sbin/ifconfig` explicitly and see what it says when you aren't root.

If the message is ok, you just need to add `/sbin` to your PATH.